# Changing color of "sticky note" box in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, you get a yellow sticky note-esque info box when hovering over code.

Since I changed my syntax highlighting to be a dark theme, light colored code does not read on this yellow stick note.

Where is the preference for this color located?  Eclipse's scattering of color preferences everywhere is extremely hard to use!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using C/C++.

Go to Preferences -> C/C++ -> Editor

In "Appearance color options", scroll down to "Source hover background", Uncheck "System Default", select a color from the color palette.

By the way, do you know how to change the hover box size?

Peter